# How to remove a file with two words separated by a space in the shell?

Tags: shell, rm

I made a text file called `hello world` in my home directory. Via the shell I am trying to remove it with the `rm` command. However, when I execute `rm hello world` the shell thinks that I am trying to delete two separate files, one called "hello" and the other called "world." How do I go about doing this correctly?

Answer (score 10):

You can quote it:

```
rm "hello world"
```

or escape the space:

```
rm hello\ world
```

Comment: Why does quoting work?

Comment: The shell works with "tokens" that are usually whitespace delimited.  Quotes (either single or double) creates a token that starts with the character following the beginning quote and ends with the character preceding the end quote.  Like @josten mentioned, make the shell pass a single token containing "hello world" instead of two tokens containing "hello" and "world".

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes its easier to remove interactively using a wildcard:

```
$ rm -i hell*
```